# Why SQL Server not displaying sys.columns.object_id properly?

Tags: sql-server-2016

when I am only fetching `sys.columns.object_id` from `sys.columns`, it displays the below result:

`select top 5 sys.columns.object_id as columns_object_id from sys.columns`

```
columns_object_id
-----------
3
3
3
3
3
```

but when I am fetching the same column `sys.columns.object_id` after joining with `sys.tables.object_id` it displays the below result:

`SELECT top 5
  c.object_id as column_Object_id,
   t.object_id as Table_Object_id
FROM
  sys.columns as c
JOIN sys.tables as t ON
  c.object_id = t.object_id`

```
column_Object_id Table_Object_id
---------------- ---------------
114099447        114099447
114099447        114099447
114099447        114099447
114099447        114099447
114099447        114099447
```

Now i want to know why the `columns.Object_id` doesn't displaying like it displaying in join query?

Comment: In the join statement, try referring to the columns by the aliases that you gave them instead of their actual column names.

Comment: @KevinVandy i did that but no changes in the result. you can see the updated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql) only has information about user tables. The `object_id` you're seeing in your first query is a system table, so that will get filtered off by your join.

Also, tables in SQL Server are unordered sets of data, and `TOP(n)` has no meaning without an accompanying `ORDER BY`. So that's part of it, too.

Try these variations to see what I mean. I obviously have different user tables than you do, so the results I get are meaningless to you, but you'll see the difference between them on your system:

```
SELECT --Returns 3 for me, too.
  TOP 5
  OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
 ,c.object_id as columns_object_id
FROM
  sys.columns AS c;

SELECT --Returns the first user table's data.
  TOP 5
  OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS ObjectName
 ,c.object_id as column_Object_id
 ,t.object_id as Table_Object_id
FROM
  sys.columns AS c
JOIN
  sys.tables AS t
    ON
    c.object_id = t.object_id;
```

And now try this one, noting the `ORDER BY` and the `LEFT JOIN`, since the system table that we're looking for isn't on the table `sys.tables`:

```
SELECT
  TOP 5
  OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS ObjectName
 ,c.object_id as column_Object_id
 ,t.object_id as Table_Object_id
FROM
  sys.columns AS c
LEFT JOIN
  sys.tables AS t
    ON
    c.object_id = t.object_id
ORDER BY c.object_id
```